# Python: "FileNotFoundError" on all Subprocess calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Using Windows 7, Python 3.5.1:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'])
```

raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'])
File "D:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
File "D:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "D:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "D:\Programs\Python 3.5.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This error occurs with all subprocess calls, such as subprocess.run, subprocess.call, and subproccess.Popen. The same error happens regardless of what command is used:

```
subprocess.check_output(['['D:\path\to\exe\program.exe', 'argument'])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

As far as I can tell, this error usually occurs when the command tries to execute a nonexistent path, but I can't determine why it would occur in these cases.

Comment: Well it does not find the binary `echo`. If you want a path resolving mechanism, you should set `shell=True`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That seems to solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to include the full path to your executable. E.g.,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['/bin/echo', 'hello'])
```

(Not sure precisely where it is on Windows, though.)

Note: Using `shell=True` will also make it happen to work, but I don't recommend solving it that way because (1) your `PATH` resolution will effectively be a side-effect (you'll have a hidden dependency on the value of `PATH` at runtime), and (2) there are [security concerns](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-trap-of-shell-true-in-the-subprocess-module-6db7fc66cdfd).

Comment: In Windows OP is using, echo is a command, but not an executable program so that it may not have its path.  Thus, your method may not likely work in Windows without **shell=True**