# Problem when using ghostscript in a subprocess to convert a .ps file into a .png file, and save the last one

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, subprocess, ghostscript, postscript

I have a postscript file obtained by using the postscript method on a canvas(I created a scolled frame by using the `ScrolledFrame` class written by @furas (which uses canvas)). I want to save this postscript file as an image (a .png file) in a selected folder. Before saving, I tried to use ghostscript in a subprocess in order to convert .ps into .png, but I get the following error:

The code used is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os 
import io
import subprocess
from PIL import Image

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

#dir_path=filedialog.askdirectory()
Input = ([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]) 
color_1 = "#d1f3cd"
color_2 = "#b3ecac"
nb_color_shades=2
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sous-trame"+str(3))
sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True)
sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # resize with window

def get_max(my_list):
    m = None
    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            i = get_max(i)
        if not m or m < i:
            m = i
    return m

def grid_function(tab):    
    rows = len(tab)
    cols = len(list(zip(*tab)))
    maximum = get_max(tab)
    range_color_1 = maximum/nb_color_shades

    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            current_element = tab[x][y]
            if current_element<=range_color_1:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_1)
            elif current_element>range_color_1 :
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_2)
            label.grid (row=x,column=y)

grid_function(Input)

input_name="Sub-frame"+str(3)+".ps"
output_name="Sub-frame"+str(3)+".png"
ps=sf._canvas.postscript(file=input_name, colormode='color')
subprocess.run('gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ng/Desktop/final results/Sub-frame3.png C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.ps', shell=True, check=True, text=True)

root.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-13d6abd107a2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/test_affichage.py', wdir='C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test')

  File "C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/test_affichage.py", line 127, in <module>
subprocess.run('gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ng/Desktop/final results/Sub-frame3.png C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.ps', shell=True, check=True, text=True)

  File "C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 487, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command 'gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ng/Desktop/final results/Sub-frame3.png C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.ps' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

When looking in the current directory(folder 'test'), I can see the file 'Sub-frame3.ps', and the type indicated for its is 'file ps'.
My goal is to save the canvas created as an image into a selected folder. I have firstly tried to use postscript method and the Image module, but I also get errors. So, if you have another way to do this saving, please, show me.

Comment: In the list of arguments passed to `subprocess.Popen`, you have the *strings* `'input_name'` and `'output_name'`. Yet AFAIK, you haven't created a file named `input_name` for the `gs` program to read. I suspect that in place of the strings `'input_name'` and `'output_name'`, you want the Python variables `input_name` and `output_name` (note the lack of quotes!).

Comment: Try seeing if the advice here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847084/python-filenotfounderror-on-all-subprocess-calls

Comment: @jjramsey, thanks for this link. I have read about some common errors there and thanks to them I edited my code (by adding shell=True). This time, I get an error regarding the exit status, that is 1. The message error is: 
     CalledProcessError: Command 'gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.png C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.ps' returned non-zero exit status 1. But as I am new with bash commands, I don't understand what the point is.

Comment: That seems like progress, since it looks like you are actually managing to execute something. I'd suggest taking KenS's advice to try to execute your command line directly in a command-line terminal, without Python, to see if you can get a more informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have supplied the Ghostscript transcript (assuming you got one). If we assume that the error message is correct, then the problem is why is the file not found, and indeed **which** file is not found, Ghostscript, the input file, the output file or something else

The most likely reason is that you have not supplied the correct filename. I don't speak Python, so I'm speculating, but I can't see why you would expect 'ps' to work as an input for Ghostscript. It needs a complete filename.

[While I was writing this jjramsey added a comment that included what I was writing here, so I'll skip that].

You have not (apparently) specified a path, just a filename. So your 'input_name' appears to have the value 'Sub-frame3.ps', but that does not appear to include the full path to the file, it's just the name. You should include a full drive and path specification.

Then there's the possibility that your path includes a space (many of the paths in your trace do) and you have not apparently surrounded the filename with "". If you don't do that then Ghostscript can't tell the difference between a space which indicates separation between command line parameters, and a space which is part of a path name. If your paths do (or may) contain a space, then you should surround the path and filename with "".

Finally, your invocation is using 'gs', yet the paths indicate you are using a Windows system. The Ghostscript binary on Windows isn't called 'gs'. It's one of gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64, gswin64c depending on whether you are using the command line or windowed executable and 32 or 64 bit version.

Any or all of the above could be your problem I think.

Comment: thank you for these suggestions. You said:"If your paths do (or may) contain a space, then you should surround the path and filename with ""." . So, I should write "input_name" instead of 'input_name'?

Comment: 'Then there's the possibility that your path includes a space (many of the paths in your trace do) and you have not apparently surrounded the filenam with "".' When using `subprocess.Popen` with a list of arguments, as @Ing has done, the issue with spaces doesn't matter, because those arguments aren't being passed to a shell, but directly to some system call. Surrounding the filename with quotes would actually be detrimental, since the quotes would be treated as literal parts of the file name. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: @Ing "So, I should write "input_name" instead of 'input_name'". Don't do either one. See what I wrote above. KenS is probably right about paths, though.

Comment: Thanks to suggestions of @KenS, I edited my original code. I changed 'gs' into 'gswin64' , and created two variables (input_path and output_path), which contain the full paths of the input and output files. And I closed these paths in  r"string", because they include a space. But, I still get the same error.

Comment: Ing as I said I don't speak Python, but jjramsey says you should **not** put "" round the path as this isn't a shell execution. So try that. Make sure you can execute gswin64c from a shell too, if you can't then you may need to add it to your $PATH (again, don't speak Python, don't know how any of this works). If I were you I'd start by trying to run your command in a command shell, if that doesn't work it'll probably be easier to find out why. If it does, then you can mimic it in your code.

Comment: I tried to execute gswin64c from the shell, by using the command line: gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ng/Desktop/final results/Sub-frame3.png C:/Users/ng/Desktop/test/Sub-frame3.ps, but I get the error:  'gswin64c' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes, I have the same error with  'gswin32c'.

Comment: Have you installed Ghostscript ? Have ytou added the install directory to your $PATH.

Comment: @KenS, yes I have installed  Ghostscript , and even when I put the full path of gswin64c, I have the same error

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, but you haven't supplied enough information to say what. Your OS appears to be telling you it can't find gswin64c.exe. Try changing to the install directory for Ghostscript, do a 'dir' and make sure you can see gswin64c.exe there, then try typing gswin64c.exe at thte command line.

Comment: By putting the full path of gswin64c.exe (note the .exe) and putting paths into quotes, I make the instruction works for me. So my updated instruction is:subprocess.run(' "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile="C:/Users/rid/Desktop/results/Sub-frame4.png" "C:/Users/rid/Desktop/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps" ', shell=True)