# FileNotFound error when executing subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to run a command in python using subprocess.run
I would like to switch the working directory JUST for the execution of this command.
Also, I need to record the output and the return code.

Here is the code I have:

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run("echo \"blah\"", cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but this only returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'echo "Running ls -la" && ls -la'
```

I also tried using the following arguments:

```py
subprocess.run(["echo", "\"blah\""], cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: for this particular case (built-in shell command, string command) you need `shell=True`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: "FileNotFoundError" on all Subprocess calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847084/python-filenotfounderror-on-all-subprocess-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jean-François Fabre said, the solution is to add "shell=True" to the call

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run("echo \"blah\"", cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

`shell=True` seems to tell subprocess to use the string as a command.